# What kind of design pattern is MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns

There are three types of design patterns: behavioral, structural and creational.

MVC is also a design pattern, but I can't find what category it belongs to.

Comment: It's a bit longer since I learned it at university but I am pretty sure that MVC is an architecture and not a design pattern. 
Also read this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-architectural-style-architectural-patterns-and-design-patterns/

Comment: Thank you! I don't  know why many websites describe it as being a design pattern..

Comment: To be more precise MVC is an architectural pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC is a kind of `Architecture`.
You need to separate when it comes to say about that.